# basic question related to increment and decrement the counter in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, counter

It is a basic question. i have started learning React and i have an assignment where i have to change the values by increment and decrement buttons. I have implemented it using class component way.

but i have a doubt. Refer the below code where the value gets changed.

```
increment = () => {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1   //HERE -----------------
    });
  };
```

Why it is not like this ??

```
increment = () => {
    this.setState({
      this.state.count: this.state.count + 1    // Here ...ERROR COMES
    });
  };
```

So why it is not accessed like **this.state.count: this.state.count + 1** ??
Please let me know the reason.

Comment: Because `this` inside setState refers to the state already

Comment: @ControlAltDel, Could you please  elaborate? ..still not got it

Comment: I think it works the second way too. But you don't need to write the second way, because Objects are automatically merged based on `key`

Comment: State  is a object and `count ` is one of object's key

Comment: You could do that but then you would have to change the name of the count variable to state.count where its used at.

Comment: inside a component  the   function `this.setState`   always  takes object to update the `this.state` object inside that component   .

Comment: @PrakashReddyPotlapadu @terpinmd It does **not** work the second way. `this.state.count` is not a valid syntax for an specifying an object key. It will break.

Comment: @BrianThompson yes you are right

Comment: for giving dynamic keys, you need to wrap it in `[]`

Comment: @BrianThompson or anyone could someone please elaborate ?

Comment: @tedd ` this.setState({
      this.state.count: this.state.count + 1    // Here ...ERROR COMES
    });` this gives you syntax error. because for giving dynamic keys in objects, you need to wrap it in `[]`

Comment: @PrakashReddyPotlapadu, you're misleading the OP. This has nothing to do with dynamic keys.

Comment: @Andy, the output gets wrong, but I am  trying  to tell the it even gives syntax error in the first hand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that does not work is because assigning values within an object has a different syntax than assigning a normal variable.

To elaborate:

When you create an object you use this syntax:

```js
let myObj = {
  foo: 'bar'
}
```

Or you could do:

```js
let myObj = {}

myObj.foo = 'bar'
```

But you can't do

```js
let myObj = {
  myObj.foo: 'bar'
}
```

What you're doing with the `setState` function is creating a new object and passing it to a function.

You should just as easily write it like this:

```js
const newState = { count: this.state.count + 1 }
this.setState(newState);
```

This is why you must use the first syntax.

Then what `setState` does is merge the object you gave it with the current `this.state` and on the next render `this.state` will contain the updated values.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that `this.state.count` might be outdated, since the state is applied asynchronously. React [recommends using the updater form](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate): *"If the next state depends on the current state, we recommend using the updater function form"* For this scenario that would be: `this.setState(({count}) => ({count: count + 1}))` or `this.setState(state => ({count: state.count + 1}))` depending on the preferred syntax.

Comment: It's true, it's just a little outside the scope of this question so I opted to keep the answer shorter and more focused.

Comment: @3limin4t0r, Could you please rewrite my code in your way and explain a little bit? it will be helpful

Comment: @BrianThompson, it was a perfect explanation..Thanks a lot

Comment: @BrianThompson  in this statement this.setState(({count}) => ({count: count + 1})) , why we are using a wrapper around {count} ?

Please explain these 2 : this.setState(({count}) => ({count: count + 1})) or this.setState(state => ({count: state.count + 1}))

Comment: They both utilize the "updater" form of `setState`, in which it is passed a function instead of a new object. The function takes the previous state as its argument, and expects the new state to be returned from it. The first example @3limin4t0r gives utilizes [`destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to pull out the `count` value. The second example is the same without using destructuring. Like I said it's kindof beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: ^ The reason `{count}` and `{count: count + 1}` are wrapped with additional parentheses is to tell JavaScript this is an expression. Without the additional parentheses the engine will think you are starting a new block. You can also see this play out when executing the following in the terminal: `{a: 1}.a` will result in an error, because the engine thinks you are opening a new block while `({a: 1}).a` results in `1`. I suggest taking a look at the destructing documentation linked above. Specifically the "Object destructuring" section.

Comment: If you are not familiar with [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) you might also want to read up on those.

Comment: got it. Thanks @3limin4t0r and Brian